# Sort a View by two date columns and add a rank column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like the one below.

```
id  name    firstDate   secondDate
==  =====   =========   ==========
A1  Carol   2000-07-24  1956-07-24
A2  Victor  2000-07-24  1980-01-13
A3  Paul    1999-12-10  1985-01-10
A4  Mia     2000-06-17  1945-10-22
A5  Luke    2000-07-24  1960-03-19
```

I need to create a view with the following format:

1. Sorted on ascending order by **firstDate** column.
2. If two or more records have the same value on **firstDate** column those records will use the **secondDate** column to decide witch record will be placed first, second and so on.
3. A column **rank** will be added after **secondDate** column with a consecutive number.

Like this

```
id  name    firstDate   secondDate   rank
==  =====   =========   ==========   ====
A3  Paul    1999-12-10  1985-01-10   1
A4  Mia     2000-06-17  1945-10-22   2
A1  Carol   2000-07-24  1956-07-24   3
A5  Luke    2000-07-24  1960-03-19   4
A2  Victor  2000-07-24  1980-01-13   5
```

as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    SET @rank := 0;
    SELECT * , @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM
    (
    SELECT id , name  ,  firstDate  , secondDate
    from table1
     ORDER BY firstDate  asc, secondDate asc
    ) zz
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a8d/6)

or this

```
   SELECT * , @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM
  (
  SELECT id , name  ,  firstDate  , secondDate
  from table1
   ORDER BY firstDate  asc, secondDate asc
   ) zz, (SELECT @rank := 0) z;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a8d/3)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify echo_Me's answer:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT id , name  ,  firstDate  , secondDate , @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank 
FROM table1
ORDER BY firstDate  asc, secondDate asc
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a8d/7